# Use same variable multiple times in print

Tags: python

In Python if I want to use a variable in string while printing I do the following:

```
name = "newbie"
site = "Stack Overflow"
print("I, a %s, find %s very useful" % (name, site))
```

If I want to print `"I, a newbie, find Stack Overflow to be very very very useful'` and substitute `'very'` by a variable name, how can I do that, while still using the `name` and `site` variables?

Comment: so you want the output to be `" I a newbie find stackoverflow to be very very very useful "` ? please put things like that in quotes. also why do you have to start with the unformatted `" I a %s find %s very useful "` ? wouldnt it make more sense to use `" I a %s find %s %s useful "` as a jumpoff point if you know you are going to do something to the word "very" ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> print("I a {0} find {1} {2} {2} {2} {2} useful".format(name, site, 'very'))
I a newbie find stackoverflow very very very very useful
```

Or, using names:

```
>>> a='very'
>>> print("I a {name} find {site} {a} {a} {a} {a} useful".format(name=name, site=site, a=a))
I a newbie find stackoverflow very very very very useful
```

Or, using the local dictionary:

```
>>> print("I a {name} find {site} {a} {a} {a} {a} useful".format(**locals()))
I a newbie find stackoverflow very very very very useful
```

Comment: `string.format()` should be the standard issue way to do this type of thing

Answer (score 2):

In python to repeat any string over multiple times you can easily use `*`operator as :

```
word = "very "
print word*3
>>> very very very
```

So In the given context you can use :

```
print "I %s, find %s %s useful"% ("newbie", "stack", word*3)
>>> I newbie, find stack very very very  useful
```